# How do we assign a Series to a ChartArea?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have an array of `ChartArea area[]` and an array of `Series series[]`

What I need to do is use a different `ChartArea` for each `Series`.

This is what is usually done :

```
Chart Chart0 = new Chart();
ChartArea ChartArea0 = new ChartArea("name");
Chart0.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea0);
Series Series0 = new Series();
Chart0.Series.Add(Series0);
// link series to area here
Series0.ChartArea = "name";
```

But in my case, I cannot have a string name for each. It needs to be an array. How can I work around this?

Comment: Why does it have to be an array? And an array of what type? [ChartArea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartarea(v=vs.110).aspx) only has one constructor that takes a parameter (of type `string`). Are you trying to just pass a single `string` value in a `string` array to the constructor of `ChartArea`?

Comment: I need it to be an array as the number of ChartAreas I need is dependant on a variable number of parameters. I also tried : myString = i.ToString();
                area[i] = new ChartArea(myString); and chart.Series[i].ChartArea = Convert.ToString(i);

Comment: Then it sounds like you want to turn the creation of `ChartArea` objects into a method that takes that `string` array of names. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked a few clarifying questions in my comment, but if I go off my assumptions of the situation you expressed, here's what I would do:

```
var sourceStringArray = new string[] { "ChartArea1Name" };

Chart Chart0 = new Chart();
ChartArea ChartArea0 = new ChartArea(sourceStringArray[0]);
Chart0.ChartAreas.Add(ChartArea0);
Series Series0 = new Series();
Chart0.Series.Add(Series0);
// link series to area here
Series0.ChartArea = sourceStringArray[0];
```

I will edit my answer based on the responses to my comment.

**Edit:**

Based on your comment:

> I need it to be an array as the number of ChartAreas I need is dependant on a variable number of parameters

You would probably want to make a method that does the creation of your `ChartArea` objects. Something like:

```
private List<ChartArea> CreateChartAreas(string[] chartAreaNames)
{
    var chartAreaInstances = new List<ChartArea>();

    foreach (var chartAreaName in chartAreaNames)
    {
        var tempChart = new Chart();
        var tempChartArea = new ChartArea(chartAreaName);
        tempChart.ChartAreas.Add(tempChartArea);
        var tempSeries = new Series();
        tempChart.Series.Add(tempSeries);
        tempSeries.ChartArea = chartAreaName;
    }

    return chartAreaInstances;
}
```

Then in the main code, do something like:

```
var sourceStringArray = new string[] { "ChartArea1Name", "ChartArea2Name" };

var chartAreas = CreateChartAreas(sourceStringArray);
foreach (var chartArea in chartAreas)
{
    // Do something with your chart area instances.
}
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested this code as I don't know what your specific use case is for this.*

Comment: Well this is a very good explaination for the answer but what I also need to get around is that I have no string parameters, the number of chart areas i need is based on an integer parameter. Will I have to harcode the string names? Or is there another way?

Comment: @AditiM There are many ways to approach that depending on your specific use case. You could have a variable that contains the "base chart name" you want (like "ChartArea") and then simply append the integer to it in the `foreach` loop with something like: `string baseName = "ChartArea"; baseName += intParameterName.ToString();`